# Properly extending the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, methods, prototype, extending

I want to create a custom method that would be available inside each HTML DOM object. I achieved the desired result by prototyping the "Element" object, however, from what I've read this can lead to quite a few problems. From what I've read it is recommended to use object wrappers. How do I go about doing that?

```js
Element.prototype.myOwnMethod = function(param){
   console.log(`${this} : ${param}`);
}
document.body.myOwnMethod('abc');
//[object HTMLBodyElement] : abc
```

Comment: [ask].You are required to post a [mcve] here, within your question and not a link to your site or any third party site.

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving elements, you could first call a function which returns an object with both the element *and* your custom function, leaving the base element unchanged, like this:

```js
const setText = function(newText) {
  this.elm.textContent = newText;
}
const selectElement = selector => {
  const elm = document.querySelector(selector);
  return { elm, setText };
}

const a = selectElement('#a');
const b = selectElement('#b');

a.setText('123');
b.setText('456');
a.elm.style.color = 'green';
```

```html
<div id="a">abc</div>
<div id="b">def</div>
```

Comment: It may be interesting for somebody to explain that `setText` **must** be implemented that way and not as an arrow function due to the interpretation of the `this` keyword will behave not as intended inside an arrow function :)

Comment: This should be setup as a constructor with methods, then you quickly end up with something like jQuery or Protrotype.js or any one of a number of other DOM libraries.